# Keep styling when adding dynamic elements javascript

Tags: javascript, css

So I am trying to add some images dynamically that are uploaded from pc to a gallery div. But when I add them with their class names, their styling is the default and not their class styling. 
I know that I can add the styling dynamically when adding the image but the styling of the class is very large. Is there any possible way we can add the styling of the class but not when we add the image?

```js
function uploadImage(){
 var appendedText="<div class='p-item grid-sizer'><a class='venobox' href='images/porfolio-16-300x500.jpg'><img src='images/porfolio-16-300x500.jpg' alt=''/></a></div>";
 var x=document.getElementsByClassName("p-grid-isotope");
 x[0].appendChild(appendedText);
}
```

```html
<section class="main-section" >
    <div class="p-grid-isotope" >
     <div class="p-item grid-sizer" ></div>
     
     
    </div>
</section>

<button type="submit" id="upload-img" class="following-button" style="color: white; margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 18%" onclick="uploadImage()"><span class="icons i1"><i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>Upload to account</button>
```

Comment: Can you show a complete example of what's not working?

Comment: Css styling is applied even to dynamically added elements. Check the location you're apprending to matches your css definition path. Show us (more of) the code.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie I have added the part of the code I am having trouble with. If I place the same exact HTML in the appendedText to the p-grid-isotope div, the styling works fine but when I add it dynamically, the image would have no styling.

Comment: @Aurelien I have added the part of the code I am having trouble with. 
I have checked that all the css files are linked to the html file.

Comment: Your button can't click.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the [CSS Combinator](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#child-combinators) and keep the styles in the CSS files only.

Descendant combinator `' '`

```
.p-grid-isotope img {
... 
}
```

or use Child combinator `'>'` if the `img` is the direct child.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, in the posted example, you're trying to append a string to a DOM node. If you're going to use `appendChild`, you need to append a DOM node.

You can use `insertAdjacentHTML` to append the string of HTML:

`x[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', appendedText);`

As for your CSS, you need to include the relevant part of the stylesheet so we can see if there's a problem with it. As mentioned by others, CSS styles should be applied even on dynamically inserted elements.

My guess is something is wrong with your markup in `appendedText`, and it's not matching against the desired CSS selector.